# How to replace deprecated uib-datepicker-popup?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

Since I updated my project to `"angular-bootstrap": "~1.2.4"`, I've a warning in the console:

`uib-datepicker settings via uib-datepicker-popup attributes are deprecated and will be removed in UI Bootstrap 1.3, use datepicker-options attribute instead`

`uib-datepicker-popup` is filled by a date format or an array of date formats:

- `uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"` in my case

So in [angular bootstrap documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#datepicker) it is still shown the `deprecated` way to handle this case.

Does anyone know how to migrate to the new version?

Answer (score 5):

They have not deprecated the attribute "uib-datepicker-popup", the warning is related to all attributes listed in [datepicker docs](https://github.com/wesleycho/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker/docs) in section "Datepicker Settings". You have to provide those values by the attribute "datepicker-options".
Don't know why but those in section "Popup Settings" are not throwing the warning.

In my case I had

**JS**

```js
$scope.datepicker.format = "shortDate";
$scope.datepicker.options = {
    formatYear: "yy",
    startingDay: 1,
};
```

**HTML**

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
    ng-model="ngModel"
    uib-datepicker-popup="{{ datepicker.format }}"
    datepicker-options="datepicker.options"
    
    datepicker-append-to-body="true" 
    is-open="datepicker.opened"               
    show-button-bar="false"
    close-text="Close"
    
    min-date="minDate"
    max-date="maxDate"
    custom-class="getCustomClass"
    show-weeks="false"
    />
```

and it became

**JS**

```js
$scope.datepicker.format = 'shortDate';
$scope.datepicker.options = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1,
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    showWeeks: false,
    customClass: getCustomClass
};
```

**HTML**

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
    ng-model="ngModel"
    uib-datepicker-popup="{{ datepicker.format }}"
    datepicker-options="datepicker.options"

    datepicker-append-to-body="true" 
    is-open="datepicker.opened"               
    show-button-bar="false"
    close-text="Close" 
    />
```

---

Update
==========

[plunker reproduction](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPzVPaONRYqqfDdOyL2v)

Comment: it is `uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"` which gave me a warning, nothing else

Comment: I had the same issue. Have you checked if the warning is still fired if you remove the value `"dd-MMMM-yyyy"` and you keep only `uib-datepicker-popup`?

Comment: Added example on plunker, try to comment/uncomment the last datepicker to see that it is the source of the warning having uib-datepicker-popup without any value while the first datepicker doesn't fire any warning.

Comment: @McGiogen what is the use of having formatYear: 'yy', in dateoptions?

Comment: As you can see in the [datepicker documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), `formatYear: 'yy'` changes the format of year in year range from yyyy (ex.: 1990-1995) to yy (ex.: 90-95). In this answer it is only an example of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the upgrade guide. It works well to me.
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes

Comment: Thanks I did not reminded this doc. However it says: `Change: datepicker-popup for uib-datepicker-popup.`. But `uib-datepicker-popup` is exactly what will be depreciated...